# Cannot get value from Key JSON MySQL PHP

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, object

I am retrieving data from a MySQL database using PHP  and attempting to use JSON.stringify and JSON.parse to create an object. It works fine but I cannot get the assocaited keys/values. Just the entire object. I break this up in to parts. Here is the PHP code:

First PHP File:

```
<?php
session_start();
include("web_db_operations.php");

if(isset($_POST['recipeId']) && isset($_SESSION['email'])){
    $recipeId = $_POST['recipeId'];
    $email = $_SESSION['email'];
}
else{
    echo "Did not work";
}
    $results = getAllMyRecipesAsList_recipeTable2($email, $recipeId);
    $_SESSION['recipeResults'] = $results;
    header('location:web_selected_recipe.php');
    exit();
?>
```

Second PHP File

```
 function getAllMyRecipesAsList_recipeTable2(string $email, int $recipeId){
    include 'config.php';
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM recipeTable WHERE email = :email AND recipeId = :recipeId';
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);       
    $stmt->bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':recipeId', $recipeId, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
    $getResults = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $json = array();
    if(count($getResults) > 0){
        foreach($getResults as $row){
            $json[] = array('firstName' => $row['firstName'],
                           'lastName' => $row['lastName'],
                           'email' => $row['email'],
                           'recipeName' => $row['recipeName'],
                           'description' => $row['description'],
                           'ingredients' => $row['ingredients'],
                           'prepTime' => $row['prepTime'],
                           'steps' => $row['steps'],
                           'nutrition' => $row['nutrition'],
                           'servings' => $row['servings'],
                           'rating' => $row['rating'],
                           'tags' => $row['tags'],
                           'imagePath' => $row['imagePath'],
                           'imageName' => $row['imageName'],
                           'recipeId' => $row['recipeId']
                           );
         }
        $results = json_encode($json);
        return $results;
    }else{
        echo "no data found";
    }
    }
```

Then to retrieve in my JS file (this is just the relevant parts):

```
<script>
    <?php $results = $_SESSION['recipeResults'];
var results = <?php echo $results; ?>;
    var toString = JSON.stringify(results);
    console.log(toString);
    var parsed = JSON.parse(toString);
    console.log(parsed);
</script>
```

Logging resultAsString yields this:

```
[{"firstName":"Marcus","lastName":"Holden","email":"marcus@gmail.com","recipeName":"Aloo Paratha","description":"","ingredients":"","prepTime":"25 Minutes","steps":"","nutrition":"","servings":"","rating":"","tags":"","imagePath":"../userRecipeImages","imageName":"9110164.jpg","recipeId":"1"}]
```

Logging parsed yields this:

```
[{…}]
0:description:
"No Description", email "marcus@gmail.com", firstName:"Marcus", imageName:"9110164.jpg", imagePath:"../userRecipeImages", ingredients:"Some Ingredients",lastName:"Holden", nutrition:"Not given", prepTime:"25 Minutes", rating:"5/10", recipeId:"1", recipeName:"Aloo Paratha", servings: "6", steps:"Your Steps Here", tags:"It's bread"
```

Now, I have tried all steps to get the value associated with a key... for instance my object here is called parsed... so I have tried parsed.firstName.. returns undefined... as well as Object.keys(parsed). I cannot seem to get the keys. I would like to work with it like an array... setting content like this:

element.innerHTML = parsed[2]... etc.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're doing quite a bit more than you need to. The data is coming to you as a JSON-encoded object. Just work with it.

```
<script>
var results = <?php echo $_SESSION['recipeResults']; ?>;

var first_results = results[0]; // Each array member is one object from your result set
console.log( first_results.firstName );

console.log( results[0].firstName ); // OR specify which array index to interact directly
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I just figured this out as well. I didn't realize it was returning an object array. I thought it was just a single object. I have a tenancy to take the most convoluted path to a solution....